# Плохо обрабатываются события открытия панелей

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на панель, она открывается. Если эта панель открыта, то она должна закрыться и так должна быть только одна панель. Например, если их 3, то только одна из 3 трех должна быть открыта, а остальные закрыты.

Скрипт работает на половину: иногда, чтобы закрыть панель, нужно сделать два нажатия вместо одного, и не скрываются другие панели, когда я нажимаю на одну из них.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("panelsWrapper");
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
var actives = wrapper.getElementsByClassName('active');
for (i = 0; panels.length > i; i++) {
  panels[i].onclick = function() {
    var currentActive = actives[0];
    if (currentActive) {
      currentActive.classList.remove("active");
      var x = this.childNodes[3];
      x.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    if (currentActive !== this) {
      this.classList.add("active");
      var x = this.childNodes[3];
      x.style.maxHeight = x.scrollHeight + "px";
    }

  };
}
```

```css
.panel-collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-wrapper" id="panelsWrapper">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем отдельно хранить активную панель? При жмаке на панель либо сворачиваете её, либо сворачиваете остальные, а эту разворачиваете?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

  panels.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (this.classList.value.indexOf('active') > -1) {
        item.classList.remove("active");
      } else {
        panels.forEach(function(otherPanel) {
          otherPanel.classList.remove('active');
        });
        item.classList.add("active");
      }
    });
  });
};
```

```css
.panel-collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

.active .panel-collapse {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-wrapper" id="panelsWrapper">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Плавности анимации можно добиться, поиграв с `max-height`, но это в принципе малоинтересное занятие при блоках отличающейся высоты (особенно если отличаются сильно).